# GORM preload causes issue while using sqlmock

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-sqlmock

GORM preload is causing this error "all expectations were already fulfilled, call to Query 'SELECT * FROM "self"."xxxxxx" WHERE "xxxxxx"."l7_code" = $1' with args [{Name: Ordinal:1 Value:9920000000054}] was not expected when I am trying to use sqlmock. IF I am not using gorm preload there is no issue with sqlmock.So if we want to mock gorm preload how can we give it in sqlmock AddRow function

Answer (score 0):

After searching for hours ,I found a simple solution of using mock.ExpectQuery to mock GORM 'preload' foreign key sql query execution

Comment: Can you add a bit more information? Maybe an example? Hitting this case myself and failing to find much resources.

Comment: Adding for future readers - it was the order in which I expect the queries. The Preload `SELECT`s come after the `SELECT` of the main model being searched.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue. You might want to mock the original query first and then mock the preload query. Also, if you have multiple preloads mock them in alphabetical order of table names otherwise it will give an error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. First I wrote expected query for main query and then wrote expected query for preload. And added `s.mock.MatchExpectationsInOrder(true)`. This solved the problem.